# Non-Jew : how to do teshuva for stealing?

Tags: gentiles, repentance-teshuvah, gezel-stealing

I heard once that a Non-Jew had to pay back twice or three times the price of the object he stole to do teshuva. I can't find sources that confirm/infirm this.

How can a Non-Jew do teshuva for having stolen another Non-Jew?

Comment: Unfortunately stage one would be to find out if they can do tshuva.

Comment: @user6591, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45798/teshuva-and-non-jews

Comment: @Yishai Radvaz hilchos milachim ch 9 halacha 9.

Comment: @user6591, not [seeing](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=107857&rid=14998) what you are referring to? Anyway, perhaps build an answer to the other question?

Comment: @Yishai He says they get killed even though they do Hashava. That sounds to me like there is no tshuva for them. At least in the basic sense of the idea.

Comment: @user6591, Teshuva, no matter how sincere, never helps in Beis Din, for anyone. I think this is a subset of that issue.

Comment: @Yishai true. But that is a point when punishment is detached from repiration. I can't think of a parallel to Jewish law to compare this to. It is possible he means what you are saying, that's why I wrote that in a basic sense it sounds like they don't have tshuva.

Comment: @Yishai just hit me. modeh biknas is patur from malkus. That is somewhat parallel.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just found my answer (in french: http://www.juif.org/blogs/10001,teshouva-chez-les-non-juifs.php). If you're interested in having it, I can translate it in english!

Comment: @Andrea I let Google translate it for me:) You can always link and present a synopsis and answer your own question.

Answer (score 3):

In Ninvei they did Teshuva and it helped. Chazal say that they undid buildings in order to return a stolen beam. Seemingly, that was enough, or even extreme.

I do recall a Pirkei d'Rebbe Eliezer though, that says that 40 years later Ninvei returned to their bad ways and was destroyed. This was because they can't really do Teshuvah.