# Teshuva Gentiles

Tags: gentiles, repentance-teshuvah, afterlife

Hello I have a question: I read that teshuva does not work for non-jews.

Sources:

> https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45798/teshuva-and-non-jews

MY question would be if this is really true then what happens(in afterlife) to the sinners who believe in the Torah and that there is only one God? I mean nobody is perfect. I think everyone (or most) has sinned at some point.

Comment: See: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/51135/27180

Comment: Hello @Shmuel, i see this but https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/90375/28337 says it dont work. My question is rather what would happen if it really didn't work? Would one then have no share in the world to come, or what happens then?

Comment: @Kevin It is often said, "two Jews, three opinions". Judaism doesn't have cut and dry answers for everything. There can be 1, 2, 3 or more opinions on something. But even still, we don't have answers for what exactly happens in the afterlife, that is God's business, and no human alive can say for certain. Focus on being a good and moral person regardless.