# When Am I obligated to forgive someone?

Tags: tanach, commentaries, forgiving-mechilah

When am I obligated to forgive someone? When should one forgive and give forgiveness to another according to the Tenach and other commentaries regards it?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10360/do-i-have-to-forgive-a-repeat-offender

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I have to forgive a repeat offender?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10360/do-i-have-to-forgive-a-repeat-offender)

Comment: It seems that only after he regrets his actions see rambam daiot 6.5 and 6.9 http://www.chabad.org/910346/ (related Shulchan aruch yd 240.16 http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6694 )